# Javascript...add one day to date and change the format

Tags: javascript, date

I have this date here 2013/06/10, which comes from the database and is set in a variable called date.

I added one day to this date by doing this..

```
var endDate = new Date(date);
endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 1);
```

and now I am trying to change the format to yyyy/MM/dd

```
var finalEndDate = endDate.toString('yyyy/MM/dd');
alert(finalEndDate);
```

but this returns

Tues Jun 11 2013 Eastern Standard Time, etc.

How do I fix this?

Comment: IF you are using jQuery, consider using this plugin: http://www.datejs.com/

Comment: endDate.toString('yyyy, MMMM ,dddd')

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1056728/. In short, [`Date`'s `.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString) doesn't accept arguments. You'll need to format it manually with `getMonth()`, etc. or find a library to format dates beyond `toString()`, `toLocaleString()`, etc. [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) is a common suggestion that's still in active development.

Comment: Everything you need to know here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, `toString` does not take any arguments. It's easy to construct your format though.

```
var finalEndDate = endDate.getFullYear() + '/' + (endDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + endDate.getDate();
```

There are [several getter methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Methods) for each component of the date object to help you construct nearly any format.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly encourage you to take a look at [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

```
var str = moment(date, 'YYYY/MM/DD').add('days', 1).format('yyyy/MM/dd');
```

Note: moment doesn't know `yyyy`, what's that supposed to be? See http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/ for supported format strings.